# Rally App SDK 2.0: Create a searchable, but not editable rallytagpicker

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I believe that the rallytagpicker is definitely a useful component. However, I do not see any config field that would allow me to prevent users from being able to create new tags, while still maintaining the search functionality. Is there such a config? Or is it a necessary trade-off between functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better solution than my previous hack:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
     items: [{
         xtype: 'rallymultiobjectpicker',
         modelType: 'tag'
     }],
     renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom
 });
```

or

```
Ext.create('Rally.ui.picker.MultiObjectPicker', {
    modelType: 'tag'
});
```

That will get you a searchable tag picker without the add capability.

Comment: Great! Of course, it does make more sense to use a component that was made specifically for tags. I may use this over the rallytagpicker + hack, since there is a notification/tool tip on that particular component that states, "Type to add a tag." Would there be any way to hide that?

Comment: I found the answer to my question above.^ You would need to specify the listCfg like so --- listCfg: {emptyText: ''} I am uncertain as to whether the idea that it lets you directly input HTML, as was done to present that notification div, may raise any concerns... However, to make it clear, this is probably the better path than trying to hack the rallytagpicker, as that component actually extends the rallymultiobjectpicker. I have also found that the rallymultiobjectpicker loads quicker.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the permission system differentiates between tag assignment and tag creation at this time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by assignment vs creation. I want this field to be searchable, but not have a prompt for direct tag creation when the search query does not already exist as a tag.

Comment: I see. So there's no way around it, then. Will such an option be offered in the future? Or perhaps you can guide me in looking into implementing it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that worked in the TagPicker's [code editor in the API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.picker.TagPicker), by overriding the private method _showAddNew to be an empty function.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
     items: [{
         xtype: 'rallytagpicker',
         autoExpand: true,
         toolTipConfig: null,
         _showAddNew: Ext.emptyFn
     }],
     renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom
 });
```

It also removes the tool tip that displays when the user clicks into the search input.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If this were exposed for modification, that would be great! However, this only works within the code editor, and is not available for overwrite in external code. This seems contrary to Charles' insistence that it would be difficult to suppress this feature. There just needs to be a config field that allows for a boolean value to be set as to whether the event handler should call that function.

Comment: It will work outside of the code editor as well, either instantiating it in the same way (using the xtype name) or doing Ext.create('Rally.ui.picker.TagPicker, { 
    _showAddNew: Ext.emptyFn, 
    toolTipConfig: null }.

Comment: nOOb commenting.  Here's the full comment:
It will work outside of the code editor as well, either instantiating it in the same way (using the xtype name) or doing Ext.create('Rally.ui.picker.TagPicker, { 
    _showAddNew: Ext.emptyFn, 
    toolTipConfig: null 
});
I'm the one that told Charles it would be tricky, but then I had a second look.  And I agree, we could add another boolean in the config which we could check before calling _showAddNew.

Comment: In my defense Ben is who told me it would be hard to suppress. :) I shall now delete any evidence of my mistake.

Comment: I take full responsibility for not looking into it far enough before talking with Charles... but I can't guarantee it won't happen again.

Comment: Wow. The discussion exploded since I last looked on here, eh. Thanks for the clarification. i'm glad there are more internal developers helping to answer question. In terms of the code you presented, I swear  that little hack wasn't working before when I tried it. Unless you changed the SDK just to open that up, that is quite strange that it seems to work now. I will have to test this a bit more.